# Position a textbox on a control in a tablelayoutpanel

Tags: vb.net, location, tablelayoutpanel

I have a table layout panel on my form. 
I have put a usercontrol in one if its cells.

Now I would like to position a textbox above this usercontrol, but I am not sure how to do the positioning.
The textbox is located on the form, not in the tablelayoutpanel.

I have tried a lot with .PointToScreen, but somehow I could not get it right.

The closest I could get was

```
    Dim pt As Point
    Me._ucGrid1.PointToScreen(Me._ucGrid1.Location)

    Dim iGridOffsetTop As Integer = Me._ucGrid1.Top + pt.Y
    Dim iGridOffsetLeft As Integer = Me._ucGrid1.Left + pt.X
```

But I guess that did not take the position of the table layout panel into account.

Could somebody please tell me where I went wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
    Dim iGridOffsetTop As Integer = Me._ucGrid1.Top
    Dim iGridOffsetLeft As Integer = Me._ucGrid1.Left

    Dim pt As Point
    pt = Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Location
    iGridOffsetLeft += pt.X
    iGridOffsetTop += pt.Y
```